# Warning while running NGen: "Cannot hardbind to System.Core"

Tags: .net-framework, ngen

While running ngen on the dll's that constitute our product, one in particular comes up with this message:

```
1>    Compiling assembly C:\folder\component.dll (CLR v4.0.30319) ...
1>WARNING: Cannot hardbind to System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,     PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561999e089 because dependency does not have a native image (check FusLogVw for reason)
1>component, Version=99.99.99.99, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null <debug>
```

This happens on multiple systems, Windows 7 and XP, with .NET 4.0 installed.

I can't find anything relevant via Google, or on this site, although 
[Recurring crash: "An unhandled win32 exception occurred in mscorsvw.exe". How to diagnose/fix?](https://superuser.com/questions/275611/recurring-crash-an-unhandled-win32-exception-occurred-in-mscorsvw-exe-how-to) seems similar.

Can anyone tell me why this one particular DLL might produce this message, while none of our other components do?

Comment: what does fuseLogvw show you? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: btw, my guess is you have a bad version of a dll in your \bin, that is overriding your GAC version, and thus is throwing all your dependencies out of wack.

Comment: You need to provide the detailed reason for us to explain this failure.

Comment: I'll have to get VS installed, and get back to you.  BTW, this seems to have no effect on the running of the application.

Comment: @rojomoke, at runtime DLLs bind dynamically, so you only get a crash in your app when you run a specific line of code that that calls the dll in the wrong fashion. if you don't execute code that uses the dll, the program will appear to run fine, but will crash if an error occurs while invoking members within the dll.